How to Solve on Dependabot: Requirements to unlock update_not_possible
I am trying to implement dependabot on my Organization AZureDevOps Pipeline. We have multi repos. I am Using a script ps1 to distribute for all the repos the Github/dependabot.yaml file and the pipeline. But when testing dependabot in a repo, I have this situation and the PR's are not created:
Found 6 dependencies
 - akeyless-community/akeyless ()
 - azure/azapi ()
 - hashicorp/azurerm ()
 - hashicorp/tls ()
 - tchupp/env ()
https://dev.azure.com/hugoboss/TerraformModule/_apis/git/repositories/hb_az_virtual_machine
 --> GET 
 <-- 200 
Requirements to unlock update_not_possible
Requirements update strategy #<Dependabot::RequirementsUpdateStrategy::BumpVersionsIfNecessary>
Checking if hashicorp/azurerm  needs updating
....


Please provide the detailed YAML of your pipeline in Azure DevOps, and the detailed debugging logs of the run that has the issue occurs? When you manually run the same PowerShell script (xxx.ps1) from your local machine, does the same issue exist? If so, the problem should be with the script itself or the configurations set in the dependabot.yml file.

In addition, here I found a Dependabot Azure DevOps Extension that provide a pipeline task to run Dependabot in pipeline. you can try it in your pipeline. And here also is an example of Azure Pipelines to run Dependabot.

According to my further research and study, I found that the message "Requirements to unlock update_not_possible" is not an issue/error, it just means the dependency does not need updating.
When running Dependabot, it will always go to check to package manifests files from the default branch of the repository regardless of which branch the pipeline is running for.
For example:

If I set the required_providers in the providers.tf file like as below in the default branch.
terraform {
  required_version = ">=1.0"

  required_providers {
    akeyless = {
      source = "akeyless-community/akeyless"
      version = ">=1.3.0"
    }

    . . .
  }
}

When running Dependabot, it will always return the message "Requirements to unlock update_not_possible". Because the current latest version 1.7.0 and subsequent new versions can always match the range specified by the pattern ">=1.3.0", so no version update needed.


If I set the required_providers in the providers.tf file like as below in the default branch.
terraform {
  required_version = ">=1.0"

  required_providers {
    akeyless = {
      source = "akeyless-community/akeyless"
      version = "1.3.0"
    }

    . . .
  }
}

When running Dependabot, as long as there is a new version higher that specified by the pattern "1.3.0", it will automatically create a branch and a pull request to update the pattern from "1.3.0" to the current latest version (for example, current "1.7.0").





To let the pipeline can automatically create the branch and pull request, you can configure like as below:

In the Security hub of the repository, you need to set the following permissions to 'Allow' for identities "Project Collection Build Service ({Organization Name})" and "{Project Name} Build Service ({Organization Name})":

Contribute
Contribute to pull requests
Create branch
Force push



Sample of the .github/dependabot.yml as reference.
# .github/dependabot.yml

version: 2
updates:
- package-ecosystem: "terraform"
  directory: "/"
  schedule:
    interval: "weekly"
  open-pull-requests-limit: 10


Sample of pipeline as reference.
# azure-pipelines.yml

. . .

steps:
- task: dependabot@1
  displayName: 'Run Dependabot'


Result: See above screenshots.



